# Is there a way to remove quotes in a C macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros, stringify

Suppose I want to *un-stringify* the macro argument which should transform `"text"` to `text`.

```
#define UN_STRINGIFY(x) /* some macro magic here */
```

Now calling this macro will remove `""` from its argument

```
UN_STRINGIFY("text") // results in ----> text
```

This would be the opposite of macro stringification:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
```

Is this possible, or am I playing with macro evilness?

Comment: What you wanted to do, if it was possible ?

Comment: That is not possible; out of curiosity, what's the intended use?

Comment: Well, normally I would just use stringify, but I'm refactoring some macros and don't really want to change the calling pattern. `#define THIS_MACRO(sringParam) const char* var = stringParam;` would change to `#define THIS_MACRO(stringParam) const char* un##stringParam = stringParam;`.

Comment: I would just use a regex search-and-replace to fix them all at the source level and be done with it...

Comment: Another possible use would be to pass in "strings" that will be used to construct identifiers, some of which might have existing CPP macro definitions. Since you only want to use those "strings" to build actual identifier names, you wouldn't want the existing CPP macro to operate on it. #ifdef/#undef/push_macro is a way to accomplish this, but it's pretty noisy in terms of readability.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not possible. And that's probably a good thing: If you pass a string you assume you can put pretty much everything in it. Un-stringifying it would suddenly result in the compiler actually caring about the contents of that string.

Comment: tbh i dont buy this argument: "Un-stringifying it would suddenly result in the compiler actually caring about the contents of that string". If you have `#define FOO(x) x` then `x` can be almost anything, and of course the comppiler cares about what `x` is. Consider `auto f = "some string"; FOO(some string)`, here `x` is just a string without the quotes. Afaik the compier does not even know if the code it gets to process is the result of a macro expansion.

Comment: "here x is just a string without the quotes." - No, `x` is a series of preprocessor tokens.

Answer (score 4):

I came to this question already several times and still I can't get it into my head. Consider this example:

```
#define FOO(x) x

// FOO( destringify("string x;"))   // no way

auto f = "string x;";
FOO(string x;)                      // hm whats the problem?
```

To me it seems obvious that it should be possible to remove the quotes. I mean `string x;` is nothing else than `"string x;"` without the quotes. The thing is: It is just not possible. I don't think there is a technical reason for that, and one can only speculate why there is no method to do it.

However, I managed to convince myself by remembering that basically all the preprocessor does is textual replacement, hence why would you want to "de-textify" something when on the level of the preprocessor anyhow everything is just text. Just do it the other way around. When I change the above example to this:

```
#define FOO(x) x
#define STR(x) STRSTR(x)
#define STRSTR(x) #x

#define STR_X string x;

auto f = STR(STR_X)
FOO(STR_X)
```

Then there is no need to de-stringify. And if you ever find yourself in the situation that you want to de-stringify a string via a macro that is not known **before** compile-time, then your are on the wrong track anyhow ;).